# Firebase storage bucket and Python - How to get nested file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-storage

So the following will work if I have a file in the root 'directory' of firebase storage (I know it's not actually a directory but the root of an object):

```
from firebase_admin import storage
storageBucket = storage.bucket()
result = storageBucket.get_blob('picture.jpg')
print(result.name)

outputs: picture.jpg
```

However, because I would obviously be storing data based on users or whatever, the path (or structure of the object tree) would be users/1fjeit4383jf/uploads/picture.jpg

Nothing I'm trying is getting to the file in the second situation. I've put the entire file path every way I can think of into get_blob() but keeps printing "None".

Is there a way to set the path before getting the blob?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your get_blob() with the entire path? This way works fine for me

```
result = storageBucket.get_blob('users/1fjeit4383jf/uploads/picture.jpg')
```